# Natural projection of the billiard phase space

Tags: abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems, billiards

**Setup**

The phase space of the billiard flow $\left\lbrace \Phi^t \right\rbrace$ ($t \in \mathbb{R}$) is given by $\Omega = \mathcal{D} \times S^1$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is a planar billiard table in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^1$ the circle.

Suppose $\mathcal{D}$ is bounded, then $\Omega$ is a torus whose cross section is $\mathcal{D}$. Specifying the location of the billiard ball by $q \in \mathcal{D}$ and its velocity vector $v \in S^1$, we call the [natural projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalProjection.html) $\pi_q(\Phi^t x), x \in \Omega$ the *billiard trajectory* on $\mathcal{D}$. This formulation is more or less a paraphrasing of that given on page 26 of the book *Chaotic Billiards* by Chernov and Markarian.

**Question(s)**

What does the billiard flow actually look like in $\Omega$ before we project it onto the table? Is it just some curve which 'flows' around in $\Omega$? Is information about the velocity $v$ lost in this projection?

**Motivation**

I am interested in how we might calculate, numerically (via simulation) the Lyapunov exponents for the flow of a billiard. While I realise this can be done via the billiard map (induced by the flow), I would like a more hands on approach. Such an approach (I assume) would amount to numerical calculations of the derivative of the projected flow $\pi_q(\Phi^t x)$ on $\mathcal{D}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding numerical calculation of Lyapunov exponents: What I was looking for but wasn't sure how to ask was a "Benettin" style approach (an approach not involving $\mathcal{D}_x \mathcal{F}$) which is covered in chapter 3 of [this](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540748663) book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "natural projection" or the "dynamics on the base" corresponds simply to forget the velocity.

The projection on the base is a movement with constant velocity until it reaches the boundary where you need to specify some reflection rule. The canon would be to have equal speed but symmetric angle (at the boundary). See for example the drawings in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards.

In order to study the Lyapunov exponents it is really better to consider only what happens on the boundary $\partial\mathcal D$.

Comment: Thanks John B. Do we also study the Lyapunov exponents by considering only what happens at the boundary if velocity is not constant? i.e. can we still make use of the derivative collision map $D_x F(x)$, where $F: M \to M \subset \Omega$. We  would need to measure the return time $\tau(x)$ differently of course.

Comment: It is very rare (and even more difficult) to consider billiards without constant velocity between collisions since the system tries to model what happens in nature and even in that case we are not yet with a complete picture. But sure, by making the right computations one could always transfer it to the boundary.

Comment: By "dynamics on the base" I assume you mean the usual picture of a billiard ball bouncing around $\mathcal{D}$.